# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when i run this code

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a web site with react and i'm receiving this error when i run this code

```
<div>
     <p>{this.props.name}, {this.props.surname}</p>
        <h3>Choose your items</h3>
        <form>
          <div id="prova">
            {this.state.items.map((item) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  {item.name}<input type="checkbox" name={item.name}
                    onChange={(e) => this.selectItem(e.target.id)}
                    checked={item.checked} />
                </div>
              )
            })}

            <br />
            <button onClick={this.addToBasket}>Add to basket</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this.state.items is undefined.
You'll have to show us more code or figure out yourself why that is.

Answer (score 0):

console.log(this.state.items) you will find it undefined, and it's a good practice making sure data exists before rendering it.

Answer (score 0):

You code is not enough for us to answer your question. you could at least show us the state. but from what i’m seeing, just make sure that items in your state in an array. you can’t use map method on objects.